# How can I render different components for each element in array with Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components

I am attempting to render contents dynamically based on a response from an external server.

Currently, the implementation is very simple, with the server returning JSON values with text corresponding to either a pure text element or a button.

```
[{
    "type": "text",
    "data": "Hello"
}, {
    "type": "button",
    "data": "World"
}]
```

In this simple setup, the `text` type should render a `<b>` element and the `button` type should render a `<button>` element. However, in the future, I plan to use larger templates with more fields in the response.

Based on this response, I would like to sequentially render the contents of a page, with the result as follows.

```
<b>Hello</b>
<button>World</button>
```

I am unsure of how one would accomplish this, though, using an array of *different* component types.

What would be the best approach to achieve this result?

Comment: refine your post to be more clear. confusing.

Comment: @Aravind Which part(s) in particular were confusing? I would be happy to edit and clarify.

Comment: you want to render a single custom component several times or more components more number of times?

Comment: @Aravind The result should look like: `<b>Hello</b><button>World</button>`. I have the `myContents` array, which contains different types of custom `Content`s; it should first use the HTML of the `TextContent`, `<b>{{text}}</b>`, with the substitution of the `text` provided when the `TextContent` was initialized in the array (`Hello`). The same goes for the `ButtonContent`, but with `<button>{{buttonText}}</button>` and `buttonText` as `World`.

Comment: This looks very "excerise-ish" and very abstract. What is it you **really** want to do? Often the problem with abstract questions is that you make suppositions on "how you think things work". This is a prime example. This boils down to "why does this not render my HTML". But instead if you described something like *"I have a list of data, and depending on a property or type it should render a different component for each"*, then I think that describes what I think you "really" want much more clearly.

Comment: @NeilLunn Your italicized question is what I was trying to get at - I would like to render a different component for each `Content` element in the array. Apologies for the confusing wording.

Comment: Kind of thought so. Note that your current attempt use "component" in the title but none of the code here is actually a component. You just have classes with a `render()` method which returns a HTML string, and guess what! That's not a component. So stop trying to tell us how you "think" it's done, and just ask us "what I want to do". Tell us your story. Your use case. Your data. And what you want to come out of that. That's how you pitch a question.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the question again, which should hopefully now better explain my overall problem and desired result.

Comment: I think this does at least come a lot clearer in intent than we started with. I do wonder somewhat if your needs are actually as simple as `ngIf` or [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html). Or if we really are talking about loading "components", as in the documentation example [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html)

Comment: @NeilLunn If possible, I would like to actually load components; the example you mentioned seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made a quick prototype that answers your needs.
The basic idea is that you should map each item in the result of the `json` response (using some `flags`) to determine the right html tag to use.
After that you should concatenate the data of each item to the constructed tag without forgetting to append the opening and closing tags at the beginning and the end of the string.
Finally append the constructed string to the `innerHTML` of the template of your component.

```
const flags = {
  text: 'b',
  button: 'button',
};

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: '<div></div>',
})
export class Example {

  public serverResponse =
    [{
      "type": "text",
      "data": "Hello"
    }, {
      "type": "button",
      "data": "World"
    }];

  private myTemplate: string = '';

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
    this.templateBuilder();
    this.elem.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.myTemplate;
  }

  private templateBuilder() {
    this.serverResponse.forEach((object) => {
      this.myTemplate += `<${flags[object['type']]}>${object['data']}</${flags[object['type']]}>\n`;
    });
  }

}
```

And that's pretty much it. Hope it helps!!